# No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute in Angular Material Table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

I have an Angular Material Table. I want to display it based by a value which can change. If the value is true, should be displayed, otherwise not. When the value is changing to true I get this error: Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute. I suppose that I didn't bind it correctly but I don't see the error.
HTML:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 layout-container" [(ngModel)]="tableIsVisible" *ngIf="tableIsVisible">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceTable">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="index">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="2">No.</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">{{ i + 1 }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="header"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements"> </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

TS:

```
tableIsVisible: boolean;
//tableIsVisible value is changing based of a function.
```

Comment: Can you show dataSourceTable in ts? [dataSource]="dataSourceTable"

Comment: My dataSource is created exactly like in Angular Material

Comment: If you comment this line -> `<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="2">No.</th>` what are happening?

Comment: Can't comment it. What I posted it just a mockup, my table is bigger. But the problem is form NgModel or ngIf.

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="tableIsVisible"` - why have you added this? div is not a form element & this is most likely the cause of the error!

Comment: Yep, you're right. Deleted ngModel and it's working properly.